# ¿Cómo hacer un botón que con un click seleccione todos los checkbox y con otro click se deseleccionen (y cambie de nombre)?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito hacer un botón que diga "Seleccionar todo" y que cuando se le dé click se seleccionen todos los checkbox y cambie su nombre a "Deseleccionar todo" para que cuando se le dé otra vez click se deseleccionen todos y cambie el nombre a "Seleccionar todo". ¿Cómo le podría hacer?

Lo hice con dos botones: uno para seleccionar todo y otro para deseleccionar todo, pero se me hace que con un botón para hacer todo eso se me haría más eficiente.

Así lo tengo con dos botones:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#BtnSeleccionar').click(function() {
    $('#meses input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
  });

  $('#BtnDeseleccionar').click(function() {
    $('#meses input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="meses" id="meses">
  <div class="reci-header">Seleccione los meses:</div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes1" value="01"> Enero<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes4" value="04"> Abril<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes7" value="07"> Julio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes10" value="10"> Octubre<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes2" value="02"> Febrero <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes5" value="05"> Mayo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes8" value="08"> Agosto<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes11" value="11"> Nov.<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes3" value="03"> Marzo <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes6" value="06"> Junio <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes9" value="09"> Sept. <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes12" value="12"> Dic. <br>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="BtnSeleccionar" value="Seleccionar todo">
  <input type="button" id="BtnDeseleccionar" value="Deseleccionar todo">
</div>
```

Comment: Y qué has intentado ? Primero intenta, luego pregunta.

Comment: En php te digo ya que no lo vas a hacer. PHP es un lenguaje de servidor, no te va a servir para interactuar con los botones de un formulario. El lenguaje importante aquí es javascript.

Comment: @lois6b Las condicionales, lo he intentado de varias formas que he investigado, pero no me jala, por eso pregunta si tenían una idea más o menos.

Comment: Creo que esto funciona, en donde te da error?

Comment: @DanielPérez si funciona , pero quiere un boton. Ha de intentarlo primero...

Comment: No entiendo, no tiene ya dos botones?

Comment: @Muriano Gracias por la correción. :)

Comment: Ya entiendo, un solo boton,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes tener una variable `flag` que sea un bool, que te diga si esta seleccionado o no, y en dependencia de esta variable seleccionar todos o no y cambiarle el nombre del boton con jquery con `$.val()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  selected = true;
  $('#BtnSeleccionar').click(function() {
    if (selected) {
      $('#meses input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
      $('#BtnSeleccionar').val('Deseleccionar');
    } else {
      $('#meses input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
      $('#BtnSeleccionar').val('Seleccionar');
    }
    selected = !selected;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="meses" id="meses">
  <div class="reci-header">Seleccione los meses:</div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes1" value="01"> Enero<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes4" value="04"> Abril<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes7" value="07"> Julio<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes10" value="10"> Octubre<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes2" value="02"> Febrero <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes5" value="05"> Mayo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes8" value="08"> Agosto<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes11" value="11"> Nov.<br>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes3" value="03"> Marzo <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes6" value="06"> Junio <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes9" value="09"> Sept. <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes12" value="12"> Dic. <br>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="BtnSeleccionar" value="Seleccionar todo">
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Daniel. Nunca respondas solo con codigo. el codigo no es la respuesta, es una herramienta. Pon una clara explicacion de qué tiene mal el autor, o que debe hacer... y acompañalo de codigo.. Un saludo

Comment: Si, gracias, me entretuve tanto haciendo el codigo que se me olvido responderle